# PHP: add data to multidimensional json string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to add the data from one json string to another in php, but I can't get it to work properly.

These are my json strings.

json_A

```
            {
                data: [
                    {
                        date: "2018032012",
                        p: [
                            {
                                lon: -7.777,
                                lat: 66.666,
                                precip-intensity: 0.0625,
                                wind-dir: 256.50015,
                                temperature: 5.5065155,
                                wind-speed: 9.045654,
                                weather-symbol: 3,
                                pressure-sealevel: 102366.94
                            }
                            ]
                    }
                    [
            }
```

json_B

```
            {
                data: [
                    {
                        date: "2018032012",
                        p: [
                            {
                                lon: -8.888,
                                lat: 99.999,
                                precip-intensity: 0.0625,
                                wind-dir: 256.50015,
                                temperature: 5.5065155,
                                wind-speed: 9.045654,
                                weather-symbol: 3,
                                pressure-sealevel: 102366.94
                            }
                            ]
                    }
                    [
            }
```

This is my desired result

json_A

```
            {
                data: [
                    {
                        date: "2018032012",
                        p: [
                            {
                                lon: -8.888,
                                lat: 99.999,
                                precip-intensity: 0.0625,
                                wind-dir: 256.50015,
                                temperature: 5.5065155,
                                wind-speed: 9.045654,
                                weather-symbol: 3,
                                pressure-sealevel: 102366.94
                            },
                            lon: -7.777,
                                lat: 66.666,
                                precip-intensity: 0.0625,
                                wind-dir: 256.50015,
                                temperature: 5.5065155,
                                wind-speed: 9.045654,
                                weather-symbol: 3,
                                pressure-sealevel: 102366.94
                            }
                            ]
                    }
                    [
            }
```

This is my php code:

```
$a = file_get_contents('json_A', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

$b = file_get_contents('json_B', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);



$a2 = json_decode($a, true);

$b2 = json_decode($b, true);

$a2["data"][] = $b2;

echo json_encode($a2);
```

This is what I am getting:

json_A

```
            {
                data: [
                    {
                        date: "2018032012",
                        p: [
                            {
                                lon: -7.777,
                                lat: 66.666,
                                precip-intensity: 0.0625,
                                wind-dir: 256.50015,
                                temperature: 5.5065155,
                                wind-speed: 9.045654,
                                weather-symbol: 3,
                                pressure-sealevel: 102366.94
                            }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        data: [
                            {
                                date: "2018032012",
                                p: [
                                    {
                                        lon: -8.888,
                                        lat: 99.999,
                                        precip-intensity: 0.0625,
                                        wind-dir: 256.50015,
                                        temperature: 5.5065155,
                                        wind-speed: 9.045654,
                                        weather-symbol: 3,
                                        pressure-sealevel: 102366.94
                                    }
                                    ]
                            }
                            ]
                    }
            }
```

So yea I am getting the data in the other json string, but not the desired way, and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any help is much obliged!

Comment: no such thing as a JSON object.  Also, the above is not JSON, but yet another random random notation.  Do you know **[jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com)** ?

Comment: Well json_A and json_B should not be counted as a part of it...but the rest is called a json object, isn’t ? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: w3schools is not exactly a great source. JSON stands for `JavaScript Object Notation` so you can have a JS object as variable or you can have an object represented as a JSON string but a JSON object is not a thing.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info....I'm having trouble finding out how extract data out of one json object, and re-locating it into another json object.

Comment: Please remove "JSON object" from your vocabulary, no such thing (thanks w3preschool for that nonsense).  Also (again), your json is not valid json. `json_decode` will most assuredly fail on that. Copy paste the content of your files on **[jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com)** to validate them. When the pretty pic is green, you can try `json_decode`, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up, doing it a different way. Instead of merging the different json files, I made a function that could handle multiple json files.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$a2["data"][] = $b2;
```

to

```
$a2["data"]["p"][] = $b2["data"]["p"][0];
```

You can also use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge the contents of what is in "p" if there is going to be more than one object in the array.